# Numbering rows in groups with MySQL: how does it work?

Tags: mysql

There are several good posts on how to number rows within groups with MySQL, but how does the actually code work? I'm unclear on what MySQL evaluates first in the code below.

For instance, placing `@yearqt := yearqt as bloc` before the `IF()` call produces different results, and I'm unclear on the role of the `s1` subquery in initializing the `@` variables: when are they updated as MySQL runs through the data rows? Is the `order by` statement run before the `select`?

The code below selects three random records per `yearqt` group. There may be other ways to do this, but the question pertains to how the code works, not how I could do this differently or whether I can do this more efficiently. Thank you.

```
 select * from (
   select customer_id , yearqt , a ,
   IF(@yearqt = yearqt , @rownum := @rownum + 1 , @rownum := 1) as rownum , 
   @yearqt := yearqt as bloc
   from 
   ( select customer_id , yearqt , rand(123) as a from tbl
     order by rand(123)
   ) a join ( select @rownum := 0 , @yearqt := '' ) s1
   order by yearqt
 ) s2 
 where rownum <= 3
 order by bloc
```

Comment: Please update your question, you didn't aknowledge any of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to how the engine retrieves SQL `SELECT` query results. The order is roughly the following:

1. Calculate explain plan
2. Calculate sets and join them using plan's directives (`FROM` / `JOIN` phase)
3. Apply `WHERE` clause
4. Apply `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` clause
5. Apply `ORDER BY` clause
6. Projection phase: every row returned is ordered and can now be 'displayed'.

So, in respect to the variables, you now understand why there's subquery to initialize them. This subquery is evaluated only once, and at the beginning of the process.

After that, the project phase seems to treat each selected attribute in the order you decided which is the reason why puting `@yearqt := yearqt as bloc` up one attribute would changes the outcome of the next/previous `IF` statement. Since each row will be projected once, it means any work you're doing on the variables will be done as many times as the number of rows in the final resulset.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this

```
join ( select @rownum := 0 , @yearqt := '' ) s1
```

is to initialize the user-defined variables at the beginning of statement execution. Because this is a rowsource for the outer query (MySQL calls it a derived table) this will be executed BEFORE the outer query runs. We aren't really interested in what this query returns, except that it returns a single row, because of the JOIN operation.

So this inline view s1 could be omitted from the query and be replaced by a couple of SET statements that are executed immediately before the query:

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SET @yearqt := 0;
```

But then we'd have three separate statements to run, and we'd get different output from the query if these weren't run, if those variables were set to some other value. By including this in the query itself, it's a single statement, and we remove the dependency on separate SET statements.

---

This is the query that's really doing the work, whittled down to just the two expressions that matter in this case

```
 SELEECT IF(@yearqt = t.yearqt , @rownum := @rownum + 1 , @rownum := 1) as rownum 
       , @yearqt := t.yearqt as bloc
    FROM ( ... ) t
   ORDER BY t.yearqt
```

Some key points that make this "work"

MySQL processes the expressions in the SELECT list in the order that they appear in the SELECT list.

MySQL processes the rows in the order specified in the ORDER BY.

The references to user-defined variables are evaluated for each row, not once at the beginning of the statement.

Note that the MySQL Reference Manual points out that this behavior is *not* guaranteed. (So, it may change in a future release.)

So, the processing of that can be described as

for the first expression:

- compare the value of the `yearqt` column from the current row with current value of @yearqt user-defined variable
- set the value of @rownum user-defined variable
- return the result of the IF() expression in the resultset

for the second expression:

- set the value of the @yearqt user-defined variable to the value of the yearqt column from the current row
- return the value of the yearqt column in the resultset

The net effect is that for each row processed, we're comparing the value in the yearqt column to the value from the "previously" processed row, and we're saving the current value to compare to the next row.